# How to add Displacement using the Component Method?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, physics, mathematical-physics

How would I add the displacement using the Component method. So I am Given the Following:

d = 20cm [N] 
d2 =50cm [S 35 E]
d3 =100cm [ W 15 S]

what I did was I first drew them and after that I added all the x components and the y components.

After that I found the square root of that and then i found the angle but when i did all of that i got the final answer of 117 [ S 1 E ] which is wrong. The real answer should be 83cm [S 49 W].

I didn't get how they got it so that's why i am asking you so I know how to do it.

it would be good if you can show me step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You describe what you did but do not say specifically how you did it or what partial results you got.  In terms of components, the three vectors are (20, 0), (-50 cos(35), 50sin(35)), (-100 sin(15), -100 cos(15)).  Are those what you got?  Doing the trig functions, those are (20, 0), (-41, 28.6), and (-25.9, -96).  Adding those, (-46.9, -67.4).  That has length 82.1 (probably "round off error" from your "83".  The angle is given by the arctan(67.4/46.9)= arctan(1.437)= 55.1 "S of W". (A ways off your "49" degrees)

Comment: Thank you so much. I messed up on the x and y parts. I took x as my y and y as my x. But thank you so much. U saved Me